# Dictionary in protocol buffers

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, thrift

Is there any way to serialize a dictionary using protocol buffers, or I'll have to use Thrift if I need that?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874024/how-does-protobuf-net-support-for-dictionary-keyvaluepair-works

Comment: Not really duplicate. That question was about the .net-bindings. OP doesn't specify language environment.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Protobuf specification now [supports dictionaries (maps) natively](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps).

#### Original answer

People typically write down the dictionary as a list of key-value pairs, and then rebuild the dictionary on the other end.

```
message Pair {
   string key = 1;
   string value = 2;
}

message Dictionary {
   repeated Pair pairs = 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with a dynamic type? I have a `Dictionary<string,object>` that I need to serialize. =/ Was trying to investigate to see if protocol buffers could do this without a huge effort.

Comment: Well, no. Protobuf is not a general object serialization protocol. You need to define protobuf messages for all the data you want to serialize. (Honestly, if you have a <string, object> map, you should probably start by refactoring your code.)

Comment: @Mike You would have to create a field for every type it *could* be, which is a bug just waiting to happen.

Answer (score 80):

For future answer seekers, [ProtoBuf now supports Maps](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps) natively:

```
message MapMessage
{
    map<string, string> MyMap = 1;
}
```

Comment: Please note that Maps still can't be repeated.

Comment: Maps are collections, they're already repeated by definition.

Comment: The link is for proto2 syntax, but maps are also available in proto3 - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [ProtoText](https://github.com/XericZephyr/prototext) package.

Assume you want to serialize a dict `person_dict` to a pre-defined `PersonBuf` protobuf object defined in `personbuf_pb2` module.

In this case, to use ProtoText,

```
import ProtoText
from personbuf_pb2 import PersonBuf

obj = PersonBuf()
obj.update(person_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I firstly comment the @Flassari 's answer as it is really convenient.

However, in my case, I needed `map<Type, repeated AnyModel>` where :

```
enum Type {
    Undefined = 0;
    Square = 1;
    Circle = 2;
}

message AnyModel {
    string Name = 1;
}
```

*Here I just want to return a dictionary that, for each type, contain a list of AnyModel*

However, I didn't find a better workaround than the one proposed by @JesperE so I did the following: *([as you can't use enum as key in map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138002/6093604))*

```
message MyRPCBodyCall {
    map<string, AnyModels> Models = 1;
}

enum Type {
    Undefined = 0;
    Square = 1;
    Circle = 2;
}

message AnyModel {
    string Name = 1;
}

message AnyModelArray {
    repeated AnyModel AnyModels = 1;
}
```

Here I convert from/to string my enum using my chosen code languages from both server/client side

So both approaches are actually valid answers IMO, depends on your requirements.