# C# .net protocol buffers - protobuf-net support for serializing dictionary of object values?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

i'm new to protocol buffers and I am using protobuf-net for VS2010.  from what i'm reading here [Dictionary in protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194845/dictionary-in-protocol-buffers), it doesn't seem that protobuf can serialize a dictionary with object types as values. but here on his site i read this:

> Notes on types
>
> supported:
>
> custom classes that: are marked as data-contract have a parameterless
>   constructor for Silverlight: are public many common primitives etc
>   single dimension arrays: T[] List / IList
>   Dictionary / IDictionary any type which
>   implements IEnumerable and has an Add(T) method The code assumes
>   that types will be mutable around the elected members. Accordingly,
>   custom structs are not supported, since they should be immutable.

which seems like it is supported.

I can successfully compile a List of objects like so:

```
message ValuesObject {
    optional int32 SomeVal = 1;
    repeated SomeClass ListOfSomeClassTypes = 2;
}
```

This works fine for a `List<SomeClass>`.  Why cannot I serialize using protobuf-net a `Dictionary<int, SomeClass>`? What would the message look like to serialize a `Dictionary<int, SomeClass>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `Dictionary<int,SomeClass>` is perfectly serailizable with protobuf-net. Protobuf-net works *simplest* when working code-first, so: *just have a `Dictionary<int,SomeClass>` in your model. You are not required to use a .proto *at all* - that is provided mainly for cross-platform purposes. The .proto specification has no concept of a dictionary, but if you *are required* to use a .proto schema, then this is serialized as:

```
message KeyValuePairInt32SomeClass {
    required int32 Key = 1;
    required SomeClass Value = 2;
}
```

with the dictionary as

```
repeated KeyValuePairInt32SomeClass YourDictionary = [n];
```