# Google Firestore - Import data from SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need migrate data from transactions saved on an sql server database to a Firestore database. I need do this programatically from a continuous process that will reflect same data from all new transactions on Firestore.

At this moment I can't find any sdk to write data on Firestore with C#.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nascent C# SDK you could grab; check out Jon Skeet's repo here: http://jskeet.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Data/

(The following is from GitHub)

## Installation

Install the `Google.Cloud.Firestore.Data` package from NuGet. Add it to your project in the normal way (for example by right-clicking on the project in Visual Studio and choosing "Manage NuGet Packages..."). Please ensure you enable pre-release packages(for example, in the Visual Studio NuGet user interface, check the "Include prerelease" box).

## Authentication

When running on Google Cloud Platform, no action needs to be taken to authenticate.

Otherwise, the simplest way of authenticating your API calls is to download a service account JSON file then set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to refer to it. The credentials will automatically be used to authenticate. See the [Getting Started With Authentication guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) for more details.

## Getting started

Everything starts with [FirestoreDb](http://jskeet.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Data/api/Google.Cloud.Firestore.Data.FirestoreDb.html). Create an instance using the `Create` or `CreateAsync` methods, passing in your Google Cloud project ID. The default credentials will be used to authenticate with the server.

From there, you can create, fetch and modify documents, and run queries.

## Sample code

```
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);

// Create a document with a random ID in the "users" collection.
CollectionReference collection = db.Collection("users");
DocumentReference document = await collection.AddAsync(new { Name = new { First = "Ada", Last = "Lovelace" }, Born = 1815 });

// A DocumentReference doesn't contain the data - it's just a path.
// Let's fetch the current document.
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await document.SnapshotAsync();

// We can access individual fields by dot-separated path
Console.WriteLine(snapshot.GetField<string>("Name.First"));
Console.WriteLine(snapshot.GetField<string>("Name.Last"));
Console.WriteLine(snapshot.GetField<int>("Born"));

// Or deserialize the whole document into a dictionary
Dictionary<string, object> data = snapshot.ToDictionary();
Dictionary<string, object> name = (Dictionary<string, object>) data["Name"];
Console.WriteLine(name["First"]);
Console.WriteLine(name["Last"]);

// See the "data model" guide for more options for data handling.

// Query the collection for all documents where doc.Born < 1900.
Query query = collection.Where("Born", QueryOperator.LessThan, 1900);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.SnapshotAsync();
foreach (DocumentSnapshot queryResult in querySnapshot.Documents)
{
    string firstName = queryResult.GetField<string>("Name.First");
    string lastName = queryResult.GetField<string>("Name.Last");
    int born = queryResult.GetField<int>("Born");
    Console.WriteLine($"{firstName} {lastName}; born {born}");
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the repository, any idea where I can find it? I want to submit an issue, the SDK cannot serialize Dictionaries with integers as key. I understand that it uses protobuf for serializatoin, and protobuf can serialize such dictionaries as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890922/c-sharp-net-protocol-buffers-protobuf-net-support-for-serializing-dictionary).